# Deleting repeated Vals of an element from an array

Tags: c

I want to write a C program that deletes repeated values from a char array. For example, if I have the array:

```c
char arr[11]={'a','b','c','a','d','b','r','q','q','s','u'};
```

I want to store the new array without the repeated values.

So I would want

```c
char b[8]={'a','b','c','d','r','q','s','u'};
```

What I have so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n=10;
  int count = 0;
  int c, d;

  
  char a[7], b[7];

  

  char arr[11]={'a','b','c','a','d','b','r','q','q','s','u'};
    
  

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
  {
    for (d = 0; d < count; d++)
    {
      if(arr[c] == b[d])
        break;
    }
    if (d == count)
    {
      b[count] = arr[c];
      count++;
    }
  }

  printf("Array obtained after removing duplicate elements:\n");

  for (c = 0; c < count; c++)
    printf("%d\n", b[c]);

  return 0;
}
```

However when I run this I get random numbers instead of the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the values out as characters rather than as decimal numbers (which is what `%d` does). Try `printf("%c\n", b[c]);`

The integers you see printed are not "random" -- they are the ASCII codes for those characters.

Answer (score 1):

> printf("%d\n", b[c]);

Print ASCII values. The output is :

```
97 (ASCII of a)  
98 (ASCII of b)  
99 (ASCII of c)   
100 (ASCII of d)   
114 (ASCII of r)   
113 (ASCII of q)  
115 (ASCII of s)
```

Solution : Use `%c` to print the characters  `printf("%c\n", b[c]);`